# Join matrices by both colnames and rownames in R

Tags: r, join, matrix, merge

I would like to join matrices by both colnames and rownames in R:

```
m1 = matrix(c(1,2,3, 11,12,13), nrow = 2, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE,
           dimnames = list(c("r1", "r2"),
                           c("a", "b", "c")))
m2 = matrix(c(4, 5, 0, 2,3,4), nrow = 2, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE,
        dimnames = list(c("r2", "r3"),
                        c("d", "b", "c")))
```

Check m1:

```
> m1
    a  b  c
r1  1  2  3
r2 11 12 13
```

Check m2:

```
> m2
   d b c
r2 4 5 0
r3 2 3 4
```

I want to get m3 which looks like this:

```
> m3
    a  b  c d
r1  1  2  3 0
r2 11 17 13 4
r3  0  3  4 2
```

I did't find an elegant way to do so. Using the rbind.fill.matrix function in package plyr, I can indirectly get m3.

```
require(plyr)
m3 = rbind.fill.matrix(m1, m2)
rownames(m3) = c(rownames(m1), rownames(m2))
m3[is.na(m3)]=0 # replace na with zero
m3 = t(sapply(by(m3,rownames(m3),colSums),identity)) # aggregate matrix by rownames
```

I guess there must be some better ways to do so. What's your suggestion?

Comment: Where are you getting the 17 in m3?

Comment: @RichardScriven 17 comes from the position of row r2 and column b, to be specific, 17 = m1[2, 2] + m2[1, 2]

Answer (score 5):

The following seems valid:

```
tmp = rbind(as.data.frame(as.table(m1)), as.data.frame(as.table(m2)))
#tmp = aggregate(Freq ~ Var1 + Var2, tmp, sum)  #unnecessary   
xtabs(Freq ~ Var1 + Var2, tmp)
#    Var2
#Var1  a  b  c  d
#  r1  1  2  3  0
#  r2 11 17 13  4
#  r3  0  3  4  2
```

edit: As noted by @AnandaMahto, `xtabs` is a 'contingency-table' and not a 'reshape-data' function and, so, it sums by default.

Comment: You can skip the aggregate step in this case since `xtabs` will take care of summing the values.

Answer (score 1):

I used this code:

```
m1 = m1[sort(rownames(m1)),sort(colnames(m1))]
m2 = m2[sort(rownames(m2)),sort(colnames(m2))]

nr = unique(c(rownames(m1),rownames(m2)))
nc = unique(c(colnames(m1),colnames(m2)))

m3 = matrix(0,nr=length(nr),nc=length(nc),dimnames=list(nr,nc))
m3[rownames(m3)%in%rownames(m1),colnames(m3)%in%colnames(m1)]=m1

m3[rownames(m3)%in%rownames(m2),colnames(m3)%in%colnames(m2)]=m3[rownames(m3)%in%rownames(m2),colnames(m3)%in%colnames(m2)]+m2
```